# PHP get odd images from a folder

Tags: php

how can i get a `<div class="hotspot-sidebar">` to every second image(odd) without the first image. First image should get a `<div class="hotspot">`.

my code :

```
<?php

$files = glob("pages/low/*.*");


for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $firstsite = $files[0];

    if($i % 2 == 0) { 
        $echo = true;
        echo '<div class="hotspot-sidebar">';
        if($image == $firstsite) {
            echo '<div class="hotspot">';
        }
    }

    $supported_file = array (
        'gif',
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png'
    );
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
            echo '<img src="'.$image .'"/>'."<br /><br />";

    } 
}
?>
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just start for() from $i=1
for (**$i=1**; $i

Answer (score 1):

you have some issues with your code ,

first , you are asking about (odd elements) although you are check for even elements

```
if($i % 2 == 0)
```

the second thing that you are always echo `echo '<div class="hotspot-sidebar">';` , so even in your first row you will print out this html tag,

I've re-factored your code using `foreach` loops , it's pretty much easier to maintain and more readable in this context .

thanks for [nikos.svnk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2210809/nikos-svnk) for the important note

```
foreach ($files as $i => $image) {
    if($i > 0) {
        if($i % 2 != 0) {
            echo '<div class="hotspot-sidebar">';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="hotspot">';
    }

    $supported_file = array (
        'gif',
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png'
    );
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
            echo '<img src="'.$image .'"/>'."<br /><br />";

    }
}
```

Comment: this `if($i % 2 != 0)` in case of `$i = 0`  is false, so you will never reach inside the if to check for the next `if($i == 0) {`

Answer (score 1):

i solved my problem with switch case:

here my code:

```
<?php 

function isEven($pageNumber) {
    $isEven = $pageNumber % 2 == 0;
    return $isEven;
}
$files = glob("pages/low/*.jpg");
for($i=0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
echo 
'<div class="page">',
'<img class="show-modal" src="'.$image .'"/>';

switch ($i): 
    case isEven($i):
        echo
            '<div class="hotspot-sidebar">',
                '<div class="goto TShirts-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Polos-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Sweats-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Sports_Outdoor-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Tradition-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Fleece-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Jackets_Vests-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Shirts_Business_Trousers-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Workwear_Safety-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Underwear_Baby_Towels-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Caps_Hats-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Bags_Umbrellas_Accessories-sidebar"></div>',
            '</div>';
        break;
    case 0:
        echo
            '<div class="hotspot">',
                '<div class="goto TShirts-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Polos-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Sweats-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Sports_Outdoor-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Tradition-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Fleece-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Jackets_Vests-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Shirts_Business_Trousers-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Workwear_Safety-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Underwear_Baby_Towels-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Caps_Hats-sidebar"></div>',
                '<div class="goto Bags_Umbrellas_Accessories-sidebar">',  
            '</div>';
        break;
endswitch;
echo
    '</div>'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the first image through $i==0 and do the rest separatly like so:

```
$files = glob("pages/low/*.*");
$output='';

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {

    if($i==0){
      //add hotpsot
       $output.='<div class="hotspot">';
    }
    $image = $files[$i];
    $firstsite = $files[0];

    if($i % 2 == 0 && $i>0) { 
        $output.= '<div class="hotspot-sidebar">';
    }
    $supported_file = array (
        'gif',
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png'
    );
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
            $output.='<img src="'.$image .'"/>'."<br /><br /></div>";
    } 

}
echo $output;
```

Comment: in case of `$i==0` the var `$output` will concatenate both div classes